# Is there a way to change micronaut server port from CLI?

Tags: java, micronaut

As the title suggested, i'm having trouble configuring the port for a micronaut server. I would like the port to be configured from the CLI or from a properties file, not from inside the java application (i don't want to rebuild the project each time i want to change the port). I have seen that using spring the following command can be used:

```
java -jar server.jar --server.port=8888
```

Is there any similar CLI command for micronaut? Or can someone help me out configure a properties file to change the port?

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1061 and https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#runningSpecificPort

Comment: Thank you a lot! How can i set your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: You can't and doesn't matter. But next time, do a search on the web first ;-)

Comment: Belive me that I did. The micronaut guide didn't give me an example and i didn't understand from there. As for git, it really didn't pop up in my google searches. Thanks, nonetheless

Comment: But you can accept your own answer where you reference the link you were given in the comment. That way it makes it clear that your question/problem was answered/solved.

Comment: @TheodorSamson Are you having trouble accepting your own answer?

Comment: I have to wait 21 more hours until i can accept an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Run Micronaut service on port provided from commandline](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1061) there are these two opions.

```sh
$ java -Dmicronaut.server.port=7070 -jar foo-0.1-all.jar
```

or

```sh
$ MICRONAUT_SERVER_PORT=7070 java -jar foo-0.1-all.jar
```

This is the solution i was searching for. However, only the first option worked for me. Thank you PeterMmm!